# In github, can you use Jekyll layouts from your user pages in your project pages?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I you have a github account with Jekyll-rendered pages at:

```
username.github.com
```

is it possible to use the layouts from there to also render your project pages at:

```
username.github.com/projectname
```

If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and no.  You can use the layouts to render files in the `projectname` *path* of your username.github.com repo.  If, however, you put the pages into the `projectname` *repo*, that repo will not have access to the same layouts unless you copy them in.

Comment: So that begs the question, if you have both a projectname path in your username.github.com repo, and a projectname repo, which one 'wins'?

(I will test it myself if I get a moment later...)